# string.split based on nth position of comma in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have string:

```
string string1 = "0,11,22,33,5500,2000,9800,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,";
```

Now I have to split this string from 4th position of comma. I need to get values 5500,2000,9800 separately.

How can I split my string like this?

Comment: Split on comma, take the first 4 elements, join both substrings back together, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi I have posted my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202522/split-string-based-on-nth-position-of-comma. Can you please check and let me know how can i go with this

Comment: Why [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202522/split-string-based-on-nth-position-of-comma) twice ??

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ and `Skip`:

```
var array = string1.Split(',').Skip(4).ToArray();
```

If you want to limit the elements of array (just want to get the 3 values):

```
var array = string1.Split(',').Skip(4).Take(3).ToArray();
```

I assume you don't know LINQ, so rember to import namespaces in order to use `LINQ` extension methods (if not imported):

```
using System.Linq;
```

EDIT (see comments):

```
var splitted = string1.Split(',');
var firstArr = splitted.Take(4);
var secondArray = splitted.Skip(4).Take(3);
var thirdArray = splitted.Skip(7);
```

If you want to have them like a string:

```
var s1 = string.Join(",", firstArray);
var s2 = string.Join(",", secondArray);
var s3 = string.Join(",", thirdArray);
```

Comment: finally i wanted to join these split arrays. set1 will have till 0,11,22,33, set two will 5500,2000,9800 and set 3 will have rest.  Is that possible?

Comment: if my question is not clear i will post another question in detail

Comment: @pwas it should not be `Take(30)`

Comment: is it possible without using linq?

Comment: @user3894187 Yes, of course. You may parse char-by-char or use `Split` and `for` loop.

Comment: i  placed my code in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202522/split-string-based-on-nth-position-of-comma ..kindly have a look and let me know how it can be possible

Answer (score 2):

.Why don't you do it like this:

```
string string1 = "0,11,22,33,5500,2000,9800,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,";
string[] parts = string1.Split(',');
```

As the OP asked a follow up question here is his answer:

To join the parts do it like this:

```
string firstPart = string.Join(",",parts.Take(4));
string secondPart = string.Join(",",parts.Skip(4).Take(3));
string thirdPart= string.Join(",",parts.Skip(7));
```

Comment: If result is required like `5500,2000,9800` use `string.Join`. Example:    `string sResult = string.Join(",", parts); `

Comment: @user3894187 - I modified it so it can do what you want.

Comment: BTW. `Split` already returns an array, you don't have to call `ToArray` and create new instance of the same array without purpose.